# DetailView in Telerik grid Razor - set default to expanded?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik

I would like .DetailView on my Telerik grid to default to open (expanded). There will always be a .DetailView for each row.  Is there a setting I can apply within the grid?  I have searched but cannot find any documentation.  Is there a way to do this with javascript?

Thanks!

Edited to add a stripped down version of the grid:

```
@( Html.Telerik().Grid<Stuff>()
        .Name("StuffGrid")
        .DataKeys(dataKeys =>
            {
                dataKeys.Add(d => d.Id).RouteKey("id");
            })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
        {
            dataBinding.Ajax()
                .Select("", "")
                .Delete("", "");
        })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound("");
            columns.Bound("");
            columns.Command(c =>
            {
                c.Delete();
            });
        })
        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("").OnDelete(""))
        .DetailView(v => v.ClientTemplate(
                Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
                .Name("TabStrip_<#= Id #>")
                .SelectedIndex(0)
                .Items(items =>
                {
                    items.Add().Text("Dates").Content(
                            Html.Telerik().Grid<Date>()
                            .Name("Dates_<#= Id #>")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound("");
                                columns.Bound("");
                            })
                            .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                            {
                                dataBinding.Ajax().Select("", "", new { id = "", id = "" });
                            })
                            .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding(""))
                            .ToHtmlString());

                    items.Add().Text("Details").Content(
                            Html.Telerik().Grid<Details>()
                            .Name("Details_<#= Id #>")
                            .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add('').RouteKey(""))
                            .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                            {
                                dataBinding.Ajax().Select("", "", new { id = "", detailId = "" });
                            })
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound("");
                                columns.Bound("");
                            })
                            .ClientEvents(events =>
                            {
                                events.OnDataBinding("");
                            })
                            .NoRecordsTemplate("")
                            .ToHtmlString());
                })
                .ToHtmlString()
                ))
)
```

Comment: Are you using RadGrid or KendoGrid?

Comment: It's a Telerik Razor grid which exists in an MVC application originally built in 2012.  I will post the grid above.